# Prevent URL from showing using history.pushState

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to create a navigation in the CMS I am building, but it seems that every problem I fix only gives me more problems.

I want to do the following:

1. User clicks on a link: http://cms.abayocms.dev/swatch-settings/?/site/1
2. The PHP script does not detect a '/swatch/'in the URL and creates a new swatch

**Issue 1**: The URL does not change after adding a swatch, and I can't use PHP to change the header, because that is already sent!
So when a user refreshes the page, a new swatch will be created, etc, etc. 
I don't want that, so I added a step:

3. I added a new peace of code (javascript):

   ```
   location.replace(window.location + '/swatch/' + newSwatchID);
   ```

**Issue 2**: This method refreshes the page. I just want to add it to the URL and not refresh it.

4. To prevent the above issue, I tried 'history.pushState' (if supported by the browser) and I added the following code:

   ```
   history.pushState(null, null, window.location+'/swatch/'+newSwatchsetID);
   ```

**Issue 3**: This ADDS a history event, so when the user clicks the browsers 'back' button, he again ends up on the URL: http://cms.abayocms.dev/swatch-settings/?/site/1. Which AGAIN creates a new swatch.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: it looks like your friend is history.replaceState()

Comment: You're my hero!!! That works great, thanks!

Comment: that's really good to hear man, I'm going to make this as an answer and please mark it as correct so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the current state than you have to use `history.replaceState();`

Just use `history.replaceState(null, null, window.location+'/swatch/'+newSwatchsetID);`

This wont add a new state on History object so `history.back()` will reload the previous page instead of a state object.